# Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x85' in file firstday.py on line 4, but no encoding declared

Tags: python-3.x

The following code is generating the error shown in the title, please can someone explain what it means, what is causing it and how to fix?

```
year = eval(input("Enter the year: "))
day = (1+5*((year-1)%4)+4*((year-1)%100)+6*((year-1)%400))%7
print("The 1st of January",year,"falls on day",day,end = " ")
print("of the week(0=Sun,…,6=Sat).")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the Python source code file in a different encoding than UTF-8, namely [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), because you are working on Windows.

Switch your text editor to UTF-8 and run the program again.

Python 3 expects its source code to be saved as UTF-8 [unless a different encoding is declared](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). The `…` is the offending character (character code 85 in Windows-1252). This character code is invalid in UTF-8, so Python fails to read the source code and gives the error you see.

- When you re-save the file as UTF-8, the Unicode code point [HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS (U+2026)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) will be used, which becomes 3 bytes in the file (E2, 80, A6), and Python will be happy.
- Alternatively you can explicitly declare your source code to be Windows-1252, this is equally valid and will work as well.